# LinEst in VBA error2015

Tags: vba, excel

I am fairly new to VBA, and I am trying to write a small script that will output the slope over a specified range of cells based on an input box. Ideally, I would like to be able to input the starting and ending cells, and have it give the "slope" of the best fit line over those ranges. I am really struggling to get this to work. All help is greatly appreciated.

```
Sub sloper()
Dim Start As Long
Dim Finish As Long
Dim v As Variant
Dim x As Variant
Dim y As Variant

    Start = InputBox("What cell do the values start on?")
    Finish = InputBox("What cell do the values end on?")
    x = Range("E" & Start & ":E" & Finish) 'Deflection
    y = Range("B" & Start & ":B" & Finish) 'Force
    v = Application.LinEst(x, y, 1, 1) 'keeps returning the error
    Range("L7") = v

End Sub
```

Comment: So Start and Finish must be a row number? Works for me.

Comment: Start and finish would be row numbers yes.

Comment: I don't think we can usefully help without any information about your data.

Comment: The real problem that I am trying to attack, is solving for linear slopes in regions of what are S shaped force vs deflection curves. I am trying to isolate the different stiffness behaviors (force/deflection) in those regions, by evaluating in regions of similar behavior. 

The best thing that I could think of was making the graphs, and then hovering over the regions that look like they share a similar slope, and trying to determine the boundary points from there.

This is something that will need to be done over a large amount of raw data files that were received from lab testing.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe change the way you're declaring the variables, also the function LINEST need to have two ranges populated with numeric values otherwise it will return #VALUE

```
Sub sloper()
Dim Start As Long
Dim Finish As Long
Dim x As Range
Dim y As Range

Dim v As Variant

    Start = InputBox("What cell do the values start on?")
    Finish = InputBox("What cell do the values end on?")
    Set x = Range("E" & Start & ":E" & Finish) 'Deflection
    Set y = Range("B" & Start & ":B" & Finish) 'Force
    v = Application.LinEst(x, y, 1, 1) 'keeps returning the error
    Range("L7") = v

End Sub
```

Comment: hot damn hot potato. You saved me.

Comment: Awesome!, If you found my answer helpfull please mark it as an acceptable answer, that helps me alot